# Are you required to say YiHyu LeRatzon before Elokai Netzor?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

After Sim Shalom/Shalom Rav in Shemoneh 'Esreh, many Siddurim print YiHyu LeRatzon ([Tehillim 19:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2619.htm#15)) before Elokai Netzor.

Not every Siddur prints this. I don't recall which editions I've seen without it, but I am sure I have seen it.

If we say YiHyu LeRatzon at the end of Elokai Netzor, are we supposed to be saying it twice, and is the earlier instance required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Orach Chaim 122:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&pgnum=285) the Bais Yosef says that you say Yehiyu Leratzon before Elokai Netzor yet the Rama says that the Yehiyu Leratzon at the end of Elokai Netzor is adequate. The Mishna Berura in note 2 says that it is best to be Machmir and say it before Elokai Netzor also.

Comment: Is the B"Y's position that you say it before Elokai Netzor, or that you say it twice?

Comment: The Bais Yosef's position is that you say it prior to Elokai Netzor and you may say it again at the end, however it is not necessary - see next page of Mishna Berura

Comment: So, if the Rama says you can say it only at the end, is he saying the one at the end is the primary one, or is he just saying you only have to say it once, and it doesn't particularly matter where you say it; follow your local Minhag?

Comment: Do not know............

Comment: You say that the MB holds saying it both times is being machmir, but I would think that it is actually being lenient.  This is because you are saying a pasuk unnecessarily, and if there is no need, it could be shem shamayim levatalah.

Comment: When you say an entire Posuk it is not considered saying Shem Shamayim L'Vatala.

Comment: @GershonGold You would have to at least have a reason to say that entire pasuk, no?